How to get out of root in Ubuntu
I just downloaded Ubuntu and it automatically put me in root and can't get out. I'm new to linux and don't know how to get out of root mode

You'll have to describe your problem a bit more clearly for us to help you.  What exactly did you download (Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop,...?), how did you create the install media, did you successfully install, what errors did you see, what exactly do you see in this "root mode"?

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].

How I'd get out of root user would depend on how I got into it... ie. did you su or switch user to it; a simple ^D should suffice (unless you've loaded shell on shell etc thus may require a few ^D). You mention recently downloading Ubuntu, but don't tell us if this is a live or installed system; nor what product, what release.. all of which influence what is default. You also mention a root mode which I don't know what you mean by that; root is a user [level], and there is a / or root directory which is not associated with the root user.. You need to be clear with details

... or maybe they installed WSL and now want to know In WSL, how do I change from root to my user_account?
